# How to extract patterns along with dates in string using R?

Tags: r, regex, string, datetime

I want to extract the dates along with a regex pattern (dates come after the pattern) from sentences.

```
text1 <- "The number of subscribers as of December 31, 2022 of Netflix increased by 1.15% compared to the previous year."

text2 <- "Netflix's number of subscribers in January 10, 2023 has grown more than 1.50%."
```

The pattern is `number of subscribers` and then there is the date as `Month Day, Year` format. Sometimes there are `as of` or `in` or `no characters` between the pattern and dates.

I have tried the following script.

```
find_dates <- function(text){
  
  pattern <- "\\bnumber\\s+of\\s+subscribers\\s+(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+){3})" # pattern and next 3 words

  str_extract(text, pattern)

}
```

However, this extracts the in-between words too, which I would like to ignore.

Desired output:

find_dates(text1)

> 'number of subscribers December 31, 2022'

find_dates(text2)

> 'number of subscribers January 10, 2023'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach using `stringr`

```
library(stringr)

find_Dates <- function(x) paste0(str_extract_all(x, 
  "\\bnumber\\b (\\b\\S+\\b ){2}|\\b\\S+\\b \\d{2}, \\d{4}")[[1]], collapse="")
```

```
find_Dates(text1)
[1] "number of subscribers December 31, 2022"

# all texts
lapply(c(text1, text2), find_Dates)
[[1]]
[1] "number of subscribers December 31, 2022"

[[2]]
[1] "number of subscribers January 10, 2023"
```

Comment: @Raj Don't know that site. This code works anywhere where you can import `stringr`.

Answer (score 0):

```
text1 <- "The number of subscribers as of December 31, 2022 of Netflix increased by 1.15% compared to the previous year."
text2 <- "Netflix's number of subscribers in January 10, 2023 has grown more than 1.50%."


find_dates <- function(text){
  # pattern <- "(\\bnumber\\s+of\\s+subscribers)\\s+(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+){3})" # pattern and next 3 words
  pattern <- "(\\bnumber\\s+of\\s+subscribers)(?:\\s+as\\s+of\\s|\\s+in\\s+)?(\\S+(\\s+\\S+){2})" # pattern and next 3 words
  str_extract(text, pattern, 1:2)

}

find_dates(text1)
# [1] "number of subscribers" "December 31, 2022"    

find_dates(text2)
# [1] "number of subscribers" "January 10, 2023"
```